# How to wire stationary air compressor

Tags: wiring, air-compressor

I am considering purchasing a stationary air compressor to install in my home’s garage. It will require a 220-240v circuit. Currently, there is no existing circuit in my garage that can power the air compressor. In addition, there is only one remaining breaker space in my load center. The garage is located on the first floor at the front of my home, while the load center is located on the exterior of the house, on the side wall, toward the rear of my home. There is perhaps a distance of 40 feet (rough approximation) between the load center and the location where I want to install the air compressor in the garage.

Considering all these, what would be the best plan of action for wiring the stationary air compressor inside the garage? This is a two-story home with attic space where it is difficult to manuever toward the sides of the home. In other words, as I move away from the center of the attic, I would have to worry about getting my head pierced by roofing nails (if I were not wise enough to wear a hard hat, of course)! There is no basement.

The make and model of the load center is Siemens W2424L1125CU. It has 24 spaces and a 125-amp main breaker.

[image: Siemens W2424L1125CU 125-amp load center, 24 spaces]

Comment: You'll need a 2-pole breaker to run a new circuit. The easiest way to get more circuits is to go to tandem or triplex breakers, if your panel supports those, so you can replace one or more of the existing breakers. If your panel doesn't support tandem breakers, you'll have to upgrade it or add a subpanel and move at least one existing circuit over -- either way will make this project more complex/expensive. What is your brand/model of panel? A picture can help too.

Comment: As far as running the wire, that's not really possible to answer without seeing the house. You need to run a wire to the garage *somehow*: through the basement (if you have one), fishing through the attic, going through walls inside (which may require holes in the drywall), or some combination of this.

Comment: @gregmac—Basic Siemens builder grade panel. I’ll try and add a pic tomorrow and the model number before I leave for work.

Comment: Would you consider exterior conduit? Would you consider a sub-panel in the garage and moving whatever circuits are presently fed to the garage to the sub-panel?

Comment: yeah really, you have to run a heavy cable over that way anyway, might as well feed a subpanel and solve your space problem too.

Comment: @Ecnerwal—may not be a bad idea. I will definitely consider it.

Comment: @Ecnerwal—So upon preliminary research, I think external conduit and a sub-panel is going to be the solution. But, you mentioned “moving whatever circuits are presently fed to the garage to the sub-panel.” That seems like a lot more work. That is not necessary, is it? I was just thinking of running PVC conduit from main breaker panel down into ground (18" below), then travelling lengthwise along house underground and coming up from ground to subpanel located on exterior wall outside garage. Then I could take a few sections of drywall down inside garage to complete the wiring. Thoughts?

Comment: Your main panel is nearly full. You need **two** spaces for either a sub-panel or just a compressor 240V feed, but you say you have **one** space. Shifting garage circuit(s) to the new sub-panel will free up space(s) in the main panel so that you can actually run the sub-panel.

Comment: @Ecnerwal—You’re right! Totally forgot that. Well, I installed an Eaton surge protector in the main panel which is occupying two spaces. I guess I’ll have to consider just removing that. Is it true that a panel needs two blank spaces (not being used) per NEC?

Comment: No. A full panel is fine, so long as the calculated loads are reasonable. But a 240V breaker takes up two spaces in USA/Canada 240-center-tap standard wiring.

Comment: Unless you have major appearance objections I'd just run the conduit along the side of the house - it already has an exterior breaker box, so some additional electrical hardware is a wash in my opinion and a lot less fuss than digging a trench. I'd also firmly suggest identifying and labeling the circuits you have which are largely unlabeled per the picture. I would not remove the whole-house surge protector - those are a good thing to have, IMHO.

Comment: @Ecnerwal—Yeah, I plan on labeling the breakers. :) Just been busy with other things. We just bought the house last year. I actually need to make a trench anyway to pour in some termite pesticide (preventative), so I may as well just do the conduit at the same time.